# find the least of 3 values NOT including zero

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for the least of three columns `(Market, LiFo, Wgtd_Avg)`. This I can do, but exclude any of the three that are equal to zero.
I only want to find the least of those `> zero`.

```
SELECT Market, LiFo, Wgtd_Avg,
(
    CASE
        WHEN Market < LiFo AND Market < Wgtd_Avg AND Market > 0 THEN Market
        WHEN LiFo  < Wgtd_Avg AND LiFo > 0 THEN LiFo
        WHEN Wgtd_Avg > 0 THEN Wgtd_Avg
        ELSE 0
    END
) AS LeastOfThree
FROM VF_CasINV_Cost
```

Comment: Are you **POSITIVE** there are no negatives in any of those fields?

Answer (score 2):

Original answer:

```
SELECT min(Value) FROM
(
SELECT Market as Value FROM VF_CasINV_Cost WHERE Market > 0
UNION
SELECT Wgtd_Avg as Value FROM VF_CasINV_Cost WHERE Wgtd_Avg > 0
UNION
SELECT LiFo as Value FROM VF_CasINV_Cost WHERE LiFo > 0
) union_table
```

Edited after comments:

```
SELECT Market, Wgtd_Avg, LiFo, min(least) AS leastOfThree FROM
(
SELECT min(market) as market, min(Market) as least FROM VF_CasINV_Cost WHERE Market > 0
UNION
SELECT min(Wgtd_avg) as Wgtd_Avg, min(Wgtd_Avg) as least FROM VF_CasINV_Cost WHERE Wgtd_Avg > 0
UNION
SELECT min(lifo) as LiFo, min(lifo) as least FROM VF_CasINV_Cost WHERE LiFo > 0
) as union_table
```

I'm away from a computer with a sql sever, so can't test this at moment, but it should be close to working... I'll test it and edit as soon as I'm back.

Comment: Since we have no idea how big this table might be, I would suggest two changes. Use UNION ALL instead of UNION, to avoid a sort (to remove duplicates). And why not take MIN(Market), MIN(Wgtd_Avg), MIN(LiFo) in each of the three queries? If you have 10000 rows in each table, there is no reason to pull them all into the union only to take a min after the fact.

Comment: I need to do this for every row to determine the smallest value and set LeastOfThree = smallest > 0

Comment: It seems to accept the rows are not lining up:  row 1  market = 47.8 LiFo = 45.10 and wgtd_Avg = 44.94.  LeastOfThree = 4.94, the above gets 444.02? i shorten the code to: SELECT Market as Value FROM VF_CasINV_Cost WHERE Market > 0
UNION
SELECT Wgtd_Avg as Value FROM VF_CasINV_Cost WHERE Wgtd_Avg > 0
UNION
SELECT LiFo as Value FROM VF_CasINV_Cost WHERE LiFo > 0

Comment: @Pavling: This won't work. But, if I understand your intention correctly, you could add NULL placeholders to the inner SELECTs and apply aggregating to all the columns in the outer SELECT, like this (schematically): `SELECT MIN(), MIN(), MIN(), MIN() FROM (SELECT MIN(), NULL, NULL, MIN() AS least UNION ALL SELECT NULL, MIN(), NULL, MIN() AS least UNION ALL SELECT NULL, NULL, MIN(), MIN() AS least) u`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  MIN(
    CASE x.f
      WHEN 1 THEN t.Market
      WHEN 2 THEN t.Wgtd_Avg
      WHEN 3 THEN t.LiFo
    END
  ) AS MinValue
FROM VF_Cas_INV_Cost t
  INNER JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3) x (f)
    ON CASE x.f
      WHEN 1 THEN t.Market
      WHEN 2 THEN t.Wgtd_Avg
      WHEN 3 THEN t.LiFo
    END > 0
```

Comment: +1 <brain overload>That's neat... but it's wrong? No it isn't... yes it is... no... yes... no...aaaaarg</brain overload>

Comment: @Lieven: :) Maybe you are right, and I should rewrite it differently. It probably mixes two semantically different things: filtering and cross-joining. So maybe it would be a bit clearer to write it out as `… CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 UNION ALL …) x (f) WHERE CASE x.f WHEN 1 … END > 0`. What do you think?

Comment: There's not a single concept in your answer that is alien to most but it's the combination of things that makes it hard to understand. But it's one of those snippets that makes you marvel. It's beautiful. I wouldn't be able to reproduce it if my life depended on it.

Comment: @Lieven: I'm sure you are too modest, but in any event, thank you for the kind words. :)

Comment: I have just over 5000 rows.  I need the leastOfThree for each row to update the table for more calculations to come.  Your code works GREAT for finding a single value for all 5000 plus rows! Thanks!!